# Is it "Mi lernas kun Duolingo" or "Mi lernas per Duolingo"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

The prepositions *kun* and *per* can both be translated in English with *with*.

In this case, which one should I use?

Answer (score 9):

*Kun* always means "together with." *Mi lernas kun Duolingo* implies that Duolingo is learning along with you. *Per* is the right choice here.

Answer (score 4):

*Per* implies, to some extent, that it is your main method of learning.

However, you can use *kun* as well, or *ĉe*, or *en*, or *je*.

The reason is simple: I would guess what you meant even if you said *sur, sub, laŭ, apud*, because it's a website, not a physical object, so it's all about the mental image, just as with *aludi al io, danci sub muziko, beno sur vi*, etc. Anyone who claims that you "can't" use a particular preposition which makes sense to you should be able to justify the assertion—be cautious about accepting attempts to impose arbitrary *idiomatic expressions* on Esperanto, which simultaneously make it harder for no good reason and subtract from its expressiveness.

---

The other answer claims that *kun* can only mean that Duolingo is also learning. This is obviously nonsense. *Mi lernas kun instruisto* does not mean that the teacher is also learning. *Kompari tion kun io* does not mean that the thing is also comparing. *Ŝi hezitis kun la finado* does not mean that the ending is also hesitating.